# Open same browser tab if link is already opened from java

Tags: java

I am trying to open URL from my JAVA code in the default browser. below is my code

```
 Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
 if(desktop != null){
        try {
            desktop.browse(URI.create(Url));
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But everytime it opens new tab even for same URL. Is there any way I can restrict this. It should open the same tab If the URI is already open. How can I do this

Comment: But I don't think that might be inappropriate approach if you are doing it for each and every "URL".Since there might be a sceanrio you need to open different screen of same application in two different tabs.For Example in case of login screen if enter login URL even after logging in you will be redirected to default URL as per directed.So can tell me the scenario you are trying to approach this logic?

Comment: @srikanthr am trying to load manual page for my application In browser and I don't want to open it in new browser if already open.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the API that gives you any finer-grained control than "Launch the default browser and browse to the given URL".

The request from the API goes to the native desktop/window manager, and since the "default browser" can be any of dozens of programs (or even nonexistent) there is no general way to inform the browser that you want to match an existing tab/window if it already contains a given URL.

You might be able to achieve this for a specific browser that provides such an API via interprocess communication, but it would be very platform and browser specific.

You could also investigate using a user-interface testing tool. One possible example is Selenium but there are many others.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. but it wont be browser specific but I am opening this URL with default browser which can be anything. Also I didn't get your point when you says using a UI testing tool. I am using above mentioned code in my java desktop application.